# How to combine phylogenetic tree and heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, phylogeny, ggtree

I need to combine phylogenetic tree and heatmap, So I have been trying to do the same by using ggtree and phytools package in R. But, I am not successful.
My datasets are given below,

```
((org1:0.03398193,org2:0.07721021)0.7400:0.00589058,org3:0.09199544,org4:0.09205519);
```

```
data.csv
x       x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
org1    50  20  40  70  50
org2    10  15  60  78  20  
org3    40  50  40  70  20
org4    80  50  40  20  30
```

The codes been adopted by following tutorial,
http://www.randigriffin.com/2017/05/11/primate-phylogeny-ggtree.html 
The codes are given below,

```
tree = read.tree(text = "org1:0.03398193,org2:0.07721021)0.7400:0.00589058,org3:0.09199544,org4:0.09205519);")
d <- data.frame(read.csv("data.csv"))
traits <- data.frame(d, fastBM(tree))
p8 <- ggtree(tree) +  xlim(0, 125) + geom_tiplab(size = 2, offset = 17)
p9 <- gheatmap(p8, traits, offset = 0.2, width = 0.2, low = "white", high = "black", colnames_position = "top", font.size = 2)
```

When I followed the same code without any change, it works perfectly fine. But, when I tried with my data, it shows error. I do not know, how to combine my tree with the datafile by using fastBM. I guess instead of fastBM, i should use some other function. please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution, you should just put away all the argument set by Randi Griffin in his post, indeed It makes your representation wrong.

You will need these packages :

```
library(ape)
library(dplyr)
library(phytools)

# install from Bioconductor
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ggtree")

library(ggtree)


tree <- read.tree(text = "(org1:1, org2:1, (org3:0.15, org4:0.15):0.8500);")
traits <- data.frame(fastBM(tree, nsim=5))

plot(tree)

p8 <- ggtree(tree) +
  geom_tiplab(size=2) 

# add heatmap
p9 <-  gheatmap(p8,
                traits,
                offset=0.2, low="white", high="black", colnames_position = "top", font.size=2)

p9
```

This proposal is for a tree which has same branches length. But it works also for different length. In fact in his example he puts `xlim(0, 125)` because his edges length goes to 40 at most but in your example edge length is smaller. So it is better to leave R function to find the best limit for your graph.

Your data with the following format ',' will be easier to import with R :

```
x,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
org1,50,20,40,70,50
org2,10,15,60,78,20  
org3,40,50,40,70,20
org4,80,50,40,20,30
```

This code is used to import data :

```
df <- read_csv("stack.txt")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
rownames(df) <- df$x
df <- df[,-1]
```

You just need to change `traits` in `df` because you have the right name for row and column.

```
p8 <- ggtree(tree) +
  geom_tiplab(size=2) 


# add heatmap
p9 <-  gheatmap(p8,
                df,
                offset=0.2, low="white", high="black", colnames_position = "top", font.size=2)

p9
```

You may have a look to the ape package vignette at the following adress to learn how to built, by hand, like you want a data.tree object in R :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/index.html

It will help you for the rest of your work and it will help us also to help you.

Your question code isn't correct for the moment and we can't know what tree you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Remi Coulaud. It works perfectly fine. But, the heatmap is not reflecting the data.csv/stack.csv values.

Comment: The heatmap is not reflecting the data.csv/stack.csv values, Instead it reflect something else.

Comment: Thank you Remi, Just now I have improved my code of tree file. is it ok.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you Remi for your valuable time and help. It works awesome.